# Sed expansion fails

Tags: sed

During a setup program, a configuration file (log4j.properties) needs to be modified.

One line of log4j.properties contains

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/OurProductWorker.log
```

We want it to be changedto

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/OurProductWorker5.log
```

(or some similar number)

This works:

```
sed -i 's/OurProductWorker.log/'"$1.log"'/g' "log4j.properties"
```

(`$1` = a number from 1 to 9 in the function called)

This fails:

```
B_PRODUCT=OurProduct 
sed -i 's/"$B_PRODUCT"Worker.log/'"$1.log"'/g' "log4j.properties"
```

I need to use a variable because we need to be to rebrand this for OEMs, and it's obviously easier to just change a bunch of variables at the beginning of the script, rather than individual functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
sed -i 's/'"$B_PRODUCT"'Worker.log/'"$1.log"'/g' "log4j.properties"
```

You always have to 'turn off' the single-quotes to have variable expand (as you have done with $1).

I hope this helps.